# Add extra headers programatically to chrome(or any other browser) via github actions

Tags: google-chrome, cypress, github-actions

I'm creating a testframework with Cypress.
Running it locally works fine but once I push it to our repository in our company domain, I get error due to some extra headers missing.
I got this error before and was fixed by adding the Modify Headers plugin to Chrome and adding the missing header there. So no change in the framework.

I've looked into adding extra headers with cy.visit and cy.request but thry only administer the extra header on the initial request.

My next strategy is now to through github actions somehow add the extra header to the browser. But I cannot find how to do this.

Summarizing the question:
**How do I add extra headers to the browser Github actions?**